# How can I access jQuery plugin function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a jQuery plugin, which works very nicely. Inside this plugin, there is a HTML button assigned to the `togglePushy();` method, and it works nicely.

However, I want to use this method from the Javascript console. The problem is if type `$.togglePushy();`  it says it's undefined. How can I access it ?

```
$(function() {
    var pushy = $('.pushy'), //menu css class
        body = $('body'),
        container = $('#container'), //container css class
        push = $('.push'), //css class to add pushy capability
        siteOverlay = $('.site-overlay'), //site overlay
        pushyClass = "pushy-left pushy-open", //menu position & menu open class
        pushyActiveClass = "pushy-active", //css class to toggle site overlay
        containerClass = "container-push", //container open class
        pushClass = "push-push", //css class to add pushy capability
        menuBtn = $('.menu-btn, .pushy a'), //css classes to toggle the menu
        menuSpeed = 200, //jQuery fallback menu speed
        menuWidth = pushy.width() + "px"; //jQuery fallback menu width

    function togglePushy(){
        body.toggleClass(pushyActiveClass); //toggle site overlay
        pushy.toggleClass(pushyClass);
        container.toggleClass(containerClass);
        push.toggleClass(pushClass); //css class to add pushy capability
    }

    function openPushyFallback(){
        body.addClass(pushyActiveClass);
        pushy.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed);
        container.animate({left: menuWidth}, menuSpeed);
        push.animate({left: menuWidth}, menuSpeed); //css class to add pushy capability
    }

    function closePushyFallback(){
        body.removeClass(pushyActiveClass);
        pushy.animate({left: "-" + menuWidth}, menuSpeed);
        container.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed);
        push.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed); //css class to add pushy capability
    }

    menuBtn.click(function() {
        togglePushy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't look like jquery plugin to me. Try just togglePushy();

Comment: Will not work, since this code is wrapped in a anonymous function which is passed to $...

Comment: I tried  togglePushy(); and it says ReferenceError: togglePushy is not defined
Typing $.togglePushy(); will cause TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Well, since `togglePushy()` is the only line in the click handler, is there a specific reason that you can't just trigger `menuBtn.click()`?

Comment: menuBtn is also undefined. i don't know how to access properties and methods inside this object

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change `togglePushy` to something like this:

```
$.togglePushy = function(){ 
    body.toggleClass(pushyActiveClass); //toggle site overlay
    pushy.toggleClass(pushyClass);
    container.toggleClass(containerClass);
    push.toggleClass(pushClass); //css class to add pushy capability
}
```

Now you should be able to access it as $.togglePushy()

Answer (score 0):

I know not the best of the solution. But you can do this by keeping your functions outside the domaready event handler like following.

```
function togglePushy(){
    body.toggleClass(pushyActiveClass); //toggle site overlay
    pushy.toggleClass(pushyClass);
    container.toggleClass(containerClass);
    push.toggleClass(pushClass); //css class to add pushy capability
}

function openPushyFallback(){
    body.addClass(pushyActiveClass);
    pushy.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed);
    container.animate({left: menuWidth}, menuSpeed);
    push.animate({left: menuWidth}, menuSpeed); //css class to add pushy capability
}

function closePushyFallback(){
    body.removeClass(pushyActiveClass);
    pushy.animate({left: "-" + menuWidth}, menuSpeed);
    container.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed);
    push.animate({left: "0px"}, menuSpeed); //css class to add pushy capability
}

$(function() {
    var pushy = $('.pushy'), //menu css class
        body = $('body'),
        container = $('#container'), //container css class
        push = $('.push'), //css class to add pushy capability
        siteOverlay = $('.site-overlay'), //site overlay
        pushyClass = "pushy-left pushy-open", //menu position & menu open class
        pushyActiveClass = "pushy-active", //css class to toggle site overlay
        containerClass = "container-push", //container open class
        pushClass = "push-push", //css class to add pushy capability
        menuBtn = $('.menu-btn, .pushy a'), //css classes to toggle the menu
        menuSpeed = 200, //jQuery fallback menu speed
        menuWidth = pushy.width() + "px"; //jQuery fallback menu width



    menuBtn.click(function() {
        togglePushy();
    });
});
```

Then call the togglePushy() directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your togglePushy() function is defined only in the context (scope) of the jQuery closure (anonymous function). Define it in the global scope instead (elsewhere in the file and not as a "function parameter").

If you need variables from that scope, encapsulate them in a namespace (an object), or declare it as `window.togglePushy() = function() { /* ... */}`.

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  .....
  window.togglePushy()= function() {
    //to do
  } 
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.togglePushy();
    });
});
```